# Looking for tips on building an XML parser derived from general file parser

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing

I need to implement a parser class for XML files in python, and I'm required to make it a derived class from the following (incomplete) class.

```
class AbstractLogsParser(object):
    # Different test statuses
    TEST_RES_PASS = 0
    TEST_RES_FAIL = 1
    TEST_RES_SKIP = 2
    def __init__(self, logs_extension):
        """
        Base class constructor.
        @param    logs_extension  Extension of log files to parse.
        """
        self._logs_ext = '.'+logs_extension
    def get_result_by_type(self, result_type): 
        """
        Returns number of passed, failed or skipped tests.
        @param    result_type          Type of results to return.
        """
        return -1
    def generate_detailed_report(self):
        """
        Generates detailed report on each test suite.
        """
        raise Exception("generate_detailed_report is not implemented")
    def process_logs(self, folder):
        """
        Parses all log files with target extension in the specified folder. @param folder Folder to look up for log files.
        """
        raise Exception("process_logs is not implemented")
```

The derived XML parser will have methods for different metrics and statistics, but it seems that the actual parsing needs to happen in the base class. Originally I wanted to use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to do this, but I can't see how to code the methods in the base class to accommodate the inherited XML parser class I need to build.

The AbstractLogsParser constructor takes the file extension as an argument, so the `process_logs` method needs to be able to parse files of different formats. Would it be smart to use regular expressions to parse the log files line by line, assuming that the keywords in the log files are always the same? I'm just looking for some tips on how to do the implementation well.

Here is an example of an XML log file the parser should handle.

```
<test_results test_suite="GAP_CONN_001"> 
    <environment>LOCAL</environment> 
    <debug>Test suite start</debug>
    <tc_result id="conn_bv_001" result="PASS">
        <debug>Run 2 sequences</debug> 
    </tc_result>
    <tc_result id="conn_bv_002" result="FAIL" /> 
    <tc_result id="conn_bv_002" result="PASS" /> 
    <tc_result id="conn_bv_004" result="SKIP">
        <reason>No pass criteria</reason>
    </tc_result>
</test_results>
```

Comment: No, regular expressions are not suited to parsing an irregular language like XML.

Comment: The abstract class says nothing about how you'd parse the file. It has methods to return summaries. Just use elementtree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The `process_logs` method says to parse all log files. Would I then just leave the parent method blank and override it in the derived XML parser class? Should I even write code for any of the parent methods, or just override them all in the XML parser class?

Comment: Yes, `AbstractLogsParser` is an *abstract* class; it documents what interface you can use but has no implementation. Your subclass will provide the implementation of methods that would otherwise raise an exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right, that makes sense. Thanks